# Детектор openCV, замкнутый контур

Tags: python, графика, изображения

Я получил изображение границ через детектор `cvCanny`. Как теперь максимально быстро найти замкнутые контуры и координаты в него входящие?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Особенность интерфейса `cvCanny` в `openCV` такова, что эта функция просто преобразует исходное изображение в изображение с размеченными контурами объектов. *Но здесь важно, что после этого преобразования выходной результат все еще является **изображением.***

Для того, чтобы получить какое-либо представление, собственно говоря, контуров, нужно использовать фукнцию типа `findContours`, которая возвращает последовательность элементов типа `cvSeq`. Дальше все тривиально - у каждого объекта типа `cvSeq` есть флаг, сообщающий о том, замкнут контур или нет - `CV_SEQ_FLAG_CLOSED`. *Получить координаты, имея ссылку на такой объект, тоже можно достаточно очевидным образом.*

---

Отмечу, что в адаптации `openCV` для `python`, вероятно, сделаны какие-то обертки для класса `cvSeq`, поэтому решить задачу должно быть еще проще.

Если поразмышлять на тему производительности - то, готов предположить, что функция `findContours` достаточно хорошо соптимизирована и вряд ли здесь что-либо удастся сильно ускорить.

Вам, конечно, заранее известно, что результирующие контуры должны быть замкнутыми и на основании этого можно, вероятно, совершить некоторую оптимизацию метода `findContours` -> `findClosedContours`, но, честно говоря, **я очень сомневаюсь, что это будет действительно необходимо.**